# How to get DataFrame format from csv format string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Let's say that I have csv format string a='1,2,3\r4,5,6\r7,8,9\r' in python.
How can I get "3 rows x 3 columns" of DataFrame [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] from variable a?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it should be backslash, so \r, means the end of line. I modified the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `io` module to create an [in-memory text stream](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) from a string. Supposing you have a string that is actually in csv format then:

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: s = '1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9'

In [4]: print(s)
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Using `io.StringIO` just like you would a file object:

```
In [5]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
Out[5]:
   1  2  3
0  4  5  6
1  7  8  9

In [6]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), header=None)
Out[6]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
temp = [i.split(',') for i in a.split('/r')]
result = [list(map(int, i)) for i in temp[:-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be this:

Input:

```
a='1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9'
print a

1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Converting to list and then df:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
my_list = re.split("[,\n]", a)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(my_list).reshape(3,3), columns = list("abc"))
print df
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```